# Possible to delete OS X app without administer password?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I have a school issued Macbook Air and have installed some apps through the app store. I used my private Apple ID to download the apps but am not unable to remove them without the administer password which I do not have. Is there some way to delete these apps without creating another account?

Answer (score 5):

To delete an app that you downloaded from the Mac App Store without needing the admin password, try deleting it from Launchpad:

1. Open the Launchpad app. (Its icon looks like a rocketship.)
2. When Launchpad opens, start typing the name of the app in the search box (which is at the top of the screen) until the app that you’d like to delete appears on the screen.
3. If you hold down the Option key, you should see the icons start to wiggle, and there should be a “×” over each app. While continuing to hold down Option, click the “×” on an app’s icon to delete it.

With these steps, you should be able to delete Mac App Store apps from your machine without needing the admin password.

Comment: Some apps don't show the "x", but the one from the App Store that was causing problems to delete did have it.